# PrismicRichText not displaying anything

Tags: vue.js, richtext, prismic.io

I have the following barebones component:

```
<template>
  <div v-for="blog in blogs">
    <h1 class="text-lg font-medium">{{ blog.title[0].text }}</h1>
    <div v-if="blog">
      <PrismicRichText :field="blog.body" />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref, onMounted } from "vue";
import { usePrismic } from "@prismicio/vue";
import { PrismicRichText } from "@prismicio/vue";

const { client, predicate } = usePrismic();

const blogs = ref({});
async function getContent() {
  const res = await client.getByType("post");
  blogs.value = res.results.map((blog: any) => blog.data);
}

onMounted(getContent);
</script>

<style scoped></style>
```

When running this, the title is displayed just fine, but the body isn't displayed at all. I see the two nested `div`'s being displayed, but there's no content. When logging the body, it is looking correctly, an array of objects. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Hey there, have you tried logging the value of `blog.body`, or just appending it in the template with `{{ blog.body }}`? If yes, what do you see? The code above looks fine to me

Comment: Yeah i mentioned that in my post: "When logging the body, it is looking correctly, an array of objects"

Comment: Oh my bad! That's weird, your setup looks fine then :/ I'm happy to help further but I lack some context, if you're willing to open a quick issue on GitHub (https://github.com/prismicio/prismic-vue/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+sort%3Aupdated-desc) with a minimal reproduction that'd be awesome!

Comment: Thanks for your cooperation, but I found out on the prismic forums that I had to use the SliceZone component.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense indeed! Glad you found that! In case that helps for future issues, you can check out the templating section of the doc to know how to template each kind of field: https://prismic.io/docs/vue-template-content Cheers!